# Extracting information from the graph of a polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials, graphing-functions

Problem: Below is the graph of a polynomial with real coefficients

[image]

What can you say about the degree of the polynomial and about the sign of the first three and last three coefficients when written in the usual manner.

My attempt: let $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+ \cdots a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$

Clearly the degree is even as the polynomial has even (8) number of roots.

Also $P(0)>0$ and $P'(0)=0$ and $P''(0) <0$ (as we can see that 0 is a locally maxima and also the tangent is above the graph at 0).

This is wrong as pointed out in the answer:**Also, its obvious that sum of the roots of is positve (from the figure). $a_{n-1} >0$** as $a_n < 0$ since the polynomial has a global maxima and no global minima.

But I am unable to comment on the sign of $a_{n-2}$.

So, I would request someone to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$.

It doesn't seem to be stated that all of the real zeroes are in the $x$-range shown on the graph, but if you do assume that, you can certainly also conclude that the degree is even, and that $a_n$ is negative.

You can say more about the degree than that, though. Clearly it must be at least $8$ in order to allow for all of the zeroes. But if you count stationary points, you can see it must be at least $12$ -- and if you count *inflection points* it must be at least $18$.

You can't say anything about $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$, though, even with the assumption that you can see all of the zeroes.

For example, if the degree of the polynomial you see is $2n$, then adding a sufficiently small multiple of $-x^{2n+4}\pm x^{2n+3} \pm x^{2n+2}$ will not modify the graph *visibly*, and will not create any new zeroes -- so you *cannot see* whether this has already happened.

---

It is true that $-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$ is the sum of the roots, but you *don't know what the sum of the roots is*. All you can judge from the graph is the sum of the *real* roots; you can't see where there might be *complex* roots, whose real parts can easily dominate the sum of the roots.